# Hibernate: Mixing xml and annotation-based mapping for one class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I have to modify (better say enhance) an already existing entity class with some metadata. The calss's metadata is defined via annotations. But now I'd like to add some UserType definitions (hibernate-specific) to the entity class. It works well if I repeat all the metadata set via annotation in my hibernate-mapping-file but is there a way to only add my specific aspect without overwriting the annotation based stuff? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you should us some of the relevant code from the entity class?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, sorry. Of course I can:

```
@Entity
public class Thing implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private ContractNumber contractNumber;

    @Column
    private String columnViaAnnotation;

    public ContractNumber getContractNumber() {
        return contractNumber;
    }

    public void setContractNumber(ContractNumber contractNumber) {
        this.contractNumber = contractNumber;
    }

    public String getColumnViaAnnotation() {
        return columnViaAnnotation;
    }

    public void setColumnViaAnnotation(String columnViaAnnotation) {
        this.columnViaAnnotation = columnViaAnnotation;
    }
}
```

My mapping:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.mypackage.Thing">
        <id name="contractNumber" type="myType" column="contractNumber" />
    </class>
    <typedef class="com.mypackage.HibernateContractNumberConverter" name="myType" />
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The custom type works perfectly well. The datatype ContractNumber will be translated into a int and vice versa. But unfortunately the column 'columnViaAnnotation' disappears due to it's not mentioned in my mapping file. I was hoping that Hibernate is smart enough to merge both configurations (xml and annotation based). Is there any chance of doing this?